# Macbook Pro stopped syncing photos to and from iCloud suddenly

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, icloud, imac, photos

I know there is a similar question but nothing suggested there worked, unfortunately...

I have an iMac (OS v10.13.6) which has the original photos and it syncs flawlessly with an iPhone X, iCloud.com, with iPad mini and, until recently with my MBP (OSv 10.13.6) . The latter, all of a sudden, stopped syncing while the others are in sync!
I have tried:
1. unchecking "iCloud photos" and rechecking. 
2. Repaing the photo library
3. Unchecking iCloud photos >> Repair >> Recheck
4. Unchecking iCloud photo >> New library >> Recheck
5. Numerous restarts of the OS in between...

Nothing seems to help! 
Any ideas? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions found on this [Link](https://www.easeus.com/ios-tips/icloud-photos-not-syncing-to-mac.html)

> 1) Check the Internet connection on your devices, As you may know, a
>   stable network connection on your iOS device and Mac is required to
>   upload photos to iCloud. Thus, you need to make sure the Wi-Fi network
>   connection works properly on your Mac and your iPhone (or other iOS
>   devices). If you find Wi-Fi not working on your devices, learn how to
>   fix it from the related article.
>
> This is the first solution you should try when iCloud photos do not
>   sync to Mac or photos are not downloading from iCloud to Mac.
>
> 2) Check your Apple ID To sync photos across your Mac and iOS devices,
>   you have to sign in to iCloud on these devices with the same Apple ID.
>   When you find iCloud photos not syncing to your Mac, go to check your
>   Apple ID and see whether it’s the cause of the issue.
>
> 3) Turn on iCloud Photo Library and My Photo Stream To access photos
>   your photos and videos from all your devices, you need to turn on
>   iCloud Photo Library/My Photo Stream on both your iOS device and
>   computer. If iCloud photos are not syncing to your Mac, you should
>   also check whether the options are set up correctly.
>
> On iPhone/iPad: Go to Settings > [your name] > iCloud > Photos and
>   then switch on iCloud Photo Library and My Photo Stream. On Mac: Go to
>   System Preferences > iCloud, make sure Photos is selected and click
>   Options next to it. Then turn on iCloud Photo Library and My Photo
>   Stream.
>
> 4) Check your iCloud Storage Apple provides 5GB of iCloud space for
>   free. But 5GB is generally not enough for you to store your iPhone
>   photos and videos. It's possible that iCloud Photos Not Syncing to Mac
>   is due to insufficient storage in iCloud. If that’s the case, you can
>   either buy more iCloud storage or go to Apple Menu > System
>   Preferences > iCloud to manage iCloud space on your Mac.

I hope this helped fix your macbook pro.

Comment: Thank you. Wifi and network in general are fully functional. All devices are on the same Apple ID. I have iCloud photos on on all devices. My storage on iCloud is 2TB. That means that, unfortunately, i need something else to try...